# RS Server moving from one server to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, database-administration

I want your expertise on migration of reporting server to another server and making some another changes in SQL SERVER CONFIGURATION.

We do have CRM-15' on prim. in our organization. we do have more than 100 ad-hoc report built in SSRS which are being used by 30+ users throughout the organization.

When these users run these reports they get an error, I would say 1 out 5 users see following error screen when they try to run the report.[image]

Reports it self takes lot of time to load, I am trying improve the report with query optimization, but the same time I am thinking that there are other issues too!! I meant to say network, how the report server is setup!

As I mentioned previously, right now OLTP DB of CRM and Report server sits on same server!!

*DO YOU GUYS THINK PUTTING REPORT SERVER (RSDB and TempRSDB) ON SEPARATE SQL INSTANCE ON NEW PHYSICAL MACHINE OR NEW VIRTUAL MACHINE WILL IMPROVE PERFORMANCE BY SOME DEGREE??*

There is some weird things which I can not figure out on network, probably you guys can guide me where to start to diagnoses this issue!

*THE ISSUE IS WHEN I RUN QUERY A WHICH HAS FEW JOINS, GROUP BY FUNCTION ETC. VIA GOING THROUGH RDP DIRECTLY INTO SERVER WHERE SQL IS INSTALLED FOR CRM-15' , THAT QUERY TAKES 20-22 SEC (THIS IS CONSISTENCE NUMBER) BUT WHEN I LOG INTO DIFFERENT RDP WHERE SQL INSTANCE IS INSTALLED BUT I CONNECT TO SQL SERVER OF OUR CRM WHICH I BELIVE I AM GOING FROM NETWORK A TO NETWORK B WHERE SQL IS ACTUALLY INSTALLED, THAT SAME QUERY RUNS IN 13-15 SECONDS AGAIN THIS CONSITENCE NUMBER.

BASED ON MY UNDERSTANDING THIS SHOULD BE OTHERWAY AROUND!! WHEN WE RUN THE QUERY DIRECTLY ON THE SQL SERVER IT SHOULD RUN FASTER AND WHEN WE CONNECT TO THAT SQL SERVER FROM ANOTHER SERVER IT SHOULD BE SLIGHTLY SLOW OR SIMILAR DUE TO NETWORK LATENCY!!

PLEASE LET ME KNOW WHAT CAN BE THE ISSUE HERE, AS I SAID ANY INFORMATION ON NETWORK FOR ME IT WILL BE JUST STARTING POINT AND I WILL MAKE MY WAY THROUGH IT.*

WE DO HAVE STANDARD VERSION OF SQL SERVER 2012 (X64 VERSION), WHEN I CHECKED UNDER OUR MSCRM OLTP DATABASE OPTION I FOUND COMPATIBILITY LEVEL STILL AT SQL SERVER 2008(100) EVEN THOUGH WE HAVE 2012 INSTALLED AND THERE IS OPTION OF SELECTING SQL SERVER 2012(110).
SHOULD I GO AHEAD AND CHANGE IT TO 110 FROM 100? AND HOW SAFE IT IS TO DO IN LIVE SYSTEM?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Can you find out anymore information by looking in the ssrs log files on that server. You can search for the error that your user's are getting to find more detailed information, insufficient permission, for example.

Comment: First of all thanks @RossBush for replying!  Since I do get this as ticket, I can not check right away what happened with what users at what time. But I will keep my eyes open for the next time and will go through the log as soon as I get the same kid of ticket again. Ross any thoughts on network and compatibility related issues? Thanks again.

Comment: WHATS WITH ALL THE CAPITALS!?

Comment: I will try to avoid writing in capital from next time. I was just trying to differentiate the information from my side and my question\issue question

Answer (score 1):

I bet this is a configuration error. The first thing I would do would be to log into the SSRS manager directly and see if you can duplicate the error on the server. There you will probably see a different error than what you think is occurring. It is very difficult to guess what is going on. Check all your credentials, check your database connections, ensure you are passing correct parameters, etc. This [link](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/104596) provides an example of the kind of error that is reported as what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks @RossBush for your advice!